# Python3 referencing syntax help needed

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wanted to transfer a file but am not familiar with python scripts. Below is the code not sure if I can do it this way.

```
  if os.path.exists(fileName):
    outputFile = open(fileName, "ab")
  else
    outputFile = open(fileName, "wb")


  with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as response, outputFile as out_file:
             data = response.read()
             out_file.write(data)
```

Here is the error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ToshibaCopyFile.py", line 51, in <module>
    with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as response, outputFile as out_file:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/urllib/request.py", line 139, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/urllib/request.py", line 376, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/urllib/request.py", line 488, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/urllib/request.py", line 414, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/urllib/request.py", line 348, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/urllib/request.py", line 496, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 503: Service Unavailable
```

I know I could have written in this way (abit of redundant, trying to simplify it)

```
  if os.path.exists(fileName):
    with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as response, open(fileName, "ab") as out_file:
             data = response.read()
             out_file.write(data)
  else
    with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as response, open(fileName, "wb") as out_file:
             data = response.read()
             out_file.write(data)
```

Anyone advice please

Comment: What is the actual problem? Does it fail? Is there any error message? Please be specific.

Comment: `HTTP Error 503: Service Unavailable` what else do you want?

Comment: btw you also want to be doing `with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as response, open(fileName, "ab") as out_file:`

Comment: yea if I do it that way it will work, but I need to check if the file exists in order to append or write.

Comment: `mode = 'ab' if os.path.exists(fileName) else 'wb`.  Now use mode in the `open` call in the `with` header.  Only factor out what it actually variable.

Answer (score 0):

Eric,

I think you are encountering at least two problems here.  You may also be encountering an actual issue the web server from which you are trying to fetch data; but there are a couple problems with your code to address first.

First note: *urlib* doesn't seem to offer support for context management.  So I think you'll want something like this:

```
#!//usr/bin/python
import contextlib, urllib

url = 'http://stackoverflow.com/'
outfilename = '/tmp/foo.out'

with contextlib.closing(urllib.urlopen(url)) as response, open(outfilename, 'w') as output_file:
    output_file.write(response.read())
```

Notice that the *with* statement must include the calls to open the resources and the aliasing (*as*).  I don't know how opening it in the enclosing block and trying to perform the aliasing on the *with* statement line would work ... and I'm pretty sure it's not a supported syntax.  (Here's the references if you want to peruse those yourself: https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement).

Notice that I'm using a wrapper provided by *contextlib* to implement the context management around the object returned by the *urllib.urlopen()* call.

Note: in Python3 this will be slightly different:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import contextlib, urllib
url = 'http://www.stackoverflow.com/'
outfilename = '/tmp/output.out'
## Python 3 differences start here:
with contextlib.closing(urllib.request.urlopen(url)) as response, \
     open(outfilename, 'w') as output_file:
  output_file.write(str(response.read()))
## urllib.urlopen becomes urllib.request.urlopen()
## and the bytes returned by the read() method must be explicity
## converted into a string for our file write()
```

See if that helps.  Vet that code with a know-to-be-working URL; then see if you can resolve whatever issues are preventing your HTTP access to your target.

Comment: Notice that the OP is using Python 3

Comment: This is one of those cases where the differences between Python and Python3 are merely annoying.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I used the redundant way tho.